# How to loop over matrix in Octave to generate cross-term polynomial of order n

Tags: algorithm, octave, linear-algebra, polynomial-math

What I am trying to do is the following, I have an n x m sized matrix, with n rows of data and m columns. Each of these columns is a different variable (think X, Y, Z, ect...).

What I want is to output a `n x (m+f(m, i))` matrix, where i is the order of the polynomial requested, and `f(m, i)` is the number of terms, including cross terms of the polynomial.

I'll give an example, say I have a matrix with one row and three columns, and I want to return the polynomial terms up to order 3.

```
input = [x, y, z]
```

I want to get to

```
output = [x, y, z, x^2, y^2, z^2, x*y, x*z, y*z, x^3, y^3, z^3, x^2y, x^2*z, x*y^2, y^2*z, x*z^2, y*z^2, x*y*z]
```

From this we see `f(3, 3) = 16`.

I know I can do this with m nested loops, and I believe I can vectorize any algorithm over the number of rows, but it would be helpful to have a more efficient algorithm than brute force.

Comment: Numerical or symbolic? Does order of results matter, and if so, what order should it be?

Comment: That is a very good question. In the matrix it should be numerical, I'll probably build a list of strings with the symbolic function and include it as well though. But order does not matter.

Comment: @LuisMendo I would need the symbolic function in the first row, and numerical evaluations of all the rows in the input matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done numerically using the following code, should be pretty easy to do symbolically as well.

```
function MatrixWithPolynomialTerms = GeneratePolynomialTerms

(InputDataMatrix, n)
  resultMatrix = InputDataMatrix;

  [nr, nc] = size(InputDataMatrix);

  cart  = nthargout ([1:nc], @ndgrid, [0:n]);
  combs = cell2mat (cellfun (@(c) c(:), cart, "UniformOutput", false))';

  for i = 1:length(combs)
    if (sum(combs(:, i)) <= n)
      resultColumn = ones(nr, 1);
      for j = 1:nc
        resultColumn.*=(InputDataMatrix(:, j).^combs(j, i));
      end
      resultMatrix = [resultMatrix, resultColumn];
    end
  end
  MatrixWithPolynomialTerms = resultMatrix
endfunction
```